# WebHosting solutions allowing self-made Apache modules

Tags: apache, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am searching for a web hosting solution that would allow me to use my own Apache modules written in C.

Have you any idea who would offer that ?

I have dupplicated that question from ServerFault.com, maybe this question is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any host that offers dedicated servers will allow you to do this but you won't find a shared host that allows this as they won't risk compromising a server with countless other accounts on it.

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider a virtual private server (depending upon your needs) - there are many VPS hosting companies which provide full root access to make any changes you need though, as with a dedicated server, you will need to manage all other aspects of the server unless you want to pay the premium for fully-managed service.

Answer (score 1):

WebFaction is shared hosting(though they let you do a lot more than most shared hosts do) and allows you to build a custom Apache instance, along with pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I recently deployed a web application from a shared account.  Using mod_lisp would have been an obvious choice for this, but not surprisingly it was not supported by the host.  I found a way instead to [run a custom server process with a fast CGI front end](http://gcbenison.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/deploying-a-scheme-web-application-the-taubatron/), and it performs about as well as a mod_lisp - based solution would have.

Upgrading to VPS was not an option in this case; I had to work within the constraints of the shared account.  It can be frustrating not being able to install whatever Apache module you want, but with some creativity are ways around that.